# Select and count Query in VBA (Access 2010)

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a select query as part of an on_click event within a form.

```
varSQL2 = "SELECT DISTINCT(*), count(*) AS Count1" & _
          " FROM Inventory WHERE Part_ID='" & rs!Part_ID & "';"
```

I am wondering what the correct syntax for this query would be. I would like all records that match the ID and then a count of how many there are. Is this syntax correct?

It may be found that this is the correct syntax, however, I am neither getting an error nor response.

Can anyone suggest a better alternative. I have seen cases where a subquery has been used, but I don't really understand the difference between that and what I have used.

Comment: No. You cannot mix columns and group functions without a GROUP BY clause.
You have to select your rows in a query, and perform the count in another query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Sergio wrote, you need a subquery like this:

```sql
SELECT Count(*) AS Count1
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT * 
    FROM Inventory 
    WHERE Part_ID = [ rs!Part_ID ] 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

For getting a count on how many recordsets have a specific Part_ID use:

```
varSQL2 = "SELECT count(*) AS Count1" & _
          " FROM Inventory WHERE Part_ID='" & rs!Part_ID & "';"
```

Now to your used `DISTINCT(*)` : I do not know what the purpose was, because of missing explanation, but it would compress exactly equal recordsets. If you follow the idea of a relational database design (which Access is thought for), you will never have two exact table-entries in one table.

So, if you wanted to achieve anything with this distinct, please explain it in your question, that we can help you.

Comment: The distinct removes duplicates. I created a query in the query designer and I was getting duplicate results (not sure why) so I included the distinct to prevent issues.

Comment: Okay then use @andre451 's answer. But I recommend you anyway to check your database-design, because having duplicate recordsets in one table is a little bit strange except you wanted that explicitly.

Comment: asdev has a very valid point here. If `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Inventory` gives a different number of records than `SELECT * FROM Inventory`, then your table has no primary key which is bad. --- `SELECT DISTINCT` is typically used when selecting only a single or a subset of fields from a table. @LiamH

Comment: I may not have been very clear as the syntax is different. my fault. however, I have asked this as a separate question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33095886/select-query-producing-duplicate-results-of-the-same-records-access-2010)