# Select Query producing duplicate results of the same records (Access 2010)

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I had a select query, which I designed in the SQL view of the query design tool. With some of my results I found duplicates of the same records. As in there were not multiples in the table, only the query (Same Primary Key). Here is the original query.

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM Inventory AS t1 INNER JOIN Inventory AS t2 ON
t1.Part_ID = t2.Part_ID WHERE (t1.Inventory_ID<>t2.Inventory_ID);
```

I aimed to query `Inventory` for records with the same `Part_ID` (FK) but different `Inventory_ID`(PK). There is a composite key between `part_ID` (FK) and `location_ID` (FK), if that makes any difference.

I have since changed this query to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM Inventory AS t1 INNER JOIN Inventory AS t2 ON t1.Part_ID = t2.Part_ID
WHERE (t1.Inventory_ID<>t2.Inventory_ID);
```

This removes the duplicate records, however, I don't believe that my original query should produce replicate data results. I am worried that this suggests that there is something wrong with my tables?

My table looks like the following:

Thanks

Comment: Do you obtain duplicates for all of your records?

Comment: Some records are singular, mostly duplicates.... two records are repeated 3 times. I cant see any reason why when looking at my tables.

Comment: Could you have multiple times the same part_ID?

Comment: the part_ID is indexed as a 'composite' key with location_ID. so a part can exist twice, as long as its not in the same place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that you might have multiple occurences of part_ID on the INNER JOIN side of your select. So if a part with the same part_ID and a different inventory_ID exists in 2 other locations, you will get duplicates.

To check that, you could do a test on a few duplicates, or rewrite your original query with a GROUP BY instruction on the INNER JOIN side of the query.