# MS Access VBA query. Select followed by a count of the result

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33081784/select-and-count-query-in-vba-access-2010) recently. However, I don't think I knew the extent of what I was wanting to accomplish with my VBA at that time. I am using Access 2010 and creating an on_click command within a form.

So my intention is to create a query, and the approach I was going to take was as follows:

```
varSQL2 = "SELECT * FROM Inventory WHERE Part_ID=" & rs!Part_ID & ";"
Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset(varSQL2, dbOpenDynaset)
varStock_Level = rs2!Stock_Level +rs!Quantity
```

the `rs!quantity` and `rs!Part_ID` are from another query earlier in my code. `stock_level` and `part_ID` are fields in the `Inventory` table.

I now need to be able to create a query to count how many records came back as a result of varSQL2. so I can do something along the lines of:

```
varSQL2 = "SELECT * FROM Inventory WHERE Part_ID=" & rs!Part_ID & ";"
Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset(varSQL2, dbOpenDynaset)
varStock_Level = rs2!Stock_Level +rs!Quantity
    if count >1 then 
      ....[code]....
    end if
```

I don't really know where to start with this, slightly confused my self with subqueries. I believe I need 2 queries not one. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From memory:

```
rs.movelast
debug.print rs.recordCount
```

You must always `Movelast` before using `RecordCount`. I your table/query is big, it can be time consuming.

Comment: and then I refer to this is as `if rs2.recordcount>1`?

Comment: it looks to be working perfectly! As in a lot of cases, this turned out to be a lot easier than expected.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways:

1. Create a query with COUNT function (similar as you did in refered question)
2. Use your query, use the `rs2.movelast` and read count out with `rs2.RecordCount`
3. Use domain count

   `Dim lngRows As Long
   lngRows = DCount("*", "Inventory", "Part_ID='" & rs!Part_ID & "'")`